# Azure AD B2C: Custom Policy - Sign In does not work

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am new in Azure B2C. I tried to implement test app to see if we can use it in our company. I started with build-in policies and everything worked fine, but I realised that for our pourposes it is not enough. So I started to implement Custom Policies using this article from MS: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom
I implemented RestApi from the article and I the Sign-Up process seems to work fine (I tested it with my own test app and with https://jwt.ms).
The account is created, but I can not log-in... I am 100% sure that email and password are correct, but i become this User/Pass Incorrect error. When I switched to the build-in policy i tested at the very beginning - i could log in with the same email and pass. So the problem is with my custom policy. The policy itself was created by MS (there is a link to github in the article). I have changed only Tenant and some minor things referenced in the article. Does anyone had such a problem before?

Comment: Hi @MPILI. Have you [registered the IEF apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#register-identity-experience-framework-applications) and configure the custom policies with the app IDs for them?

Comment: Did you add the REST API to the custom policy? What happens if you remove it? Agree with @Chris - register the apps, update the clientID's. update the tenant names and then test. When that works, start adding API etc.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett
Thank you for your comment. I did the whole process of registrations the apps and so one and now it works.

Comment: @nzpcmad
Thank you for your comment. As I wrote to Chris - i did the whole process of registering the apps and configuration one more time and it works now (with custom rest api).

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved.

As I wrote to Chris - i did the whole process of registering the apps and configuration one more time and it works now (with custom rest api). 
I based on this tutorial -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#register-identity-experience-framework-applications